# Excel VBA, Copying Colored Rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list in "Sheet1" with three Columns, A (Account Number), B (Description) & C (Amount). Based on 1st two columns (A & B) color, I want to copy the specific row to "Sheet2" and Paste it under one specific header (I have three headers).

Example

1. Sheet1 - Cell A2 is "Red" & B2 is "Yellow", Copy/Paste Under Header "Inefficiencies" in Sheet2
2. Sheet1 - Cell A3 is "Blue" & B3 is "No Color" Copy/Paste Under Header "Effective" in Sheet2

---

```
Account Number  Description  Amount
LP001022        Graduate     3,076.00 
LP001031        Graduate     5,000.00 
LP001035        Graduate     2,340.00
```

I have taken a code from this site already, but I could not completely configure it to my needs. Thank you for the help in advance.

```
Sub lastrow()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim acell As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    MsgBox (lastrow)

    With Worksheets("Sheet3")
        j = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With

    For i = 1 To lastrow
        With Worksheets("Sheet1")
            If .Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) And _
               .Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
                   .Rows(i).Copy 'I have to give destination 
                   j = j + 1
                End If
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Your description is not clear: 1. You cannot copy an entire row under "a header" (column) - you can copy the row _starting_ at a header. 2. Where are the headers in Sheet2 (what column are "Inefficiencies" and "Effective") 3. What values do you want to copy there? 4. In your code: a cell cannot have 2 colors at the same time (`.Cells(i, 1)`)

Comment: You `If` condition will never be true.  A cell can't be both Yellow (`.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)`) and Not Coloured (`.ColorIndex = xlNone`)

Answer (score 2):

Here are the key instructions to copy a row from sheet1 to INSERT into a row in sheet2.  This assumes you have all the row numbers.

```
' -- to copy a row in sh1 to INSERT into sh2:
  sh2.Rows(irowInefficiency + 1).Insert
  sh1.Rows(irowFrom).Copy sh2.Rows(irowInefficiency + 1)
' -- you have to increment all header rows after this one
  irowEffective = irowEffective + 1
```

The following puts these in context:

```
Sub sub1() ' copy/insert a row
  Dim irowFrom&, irowInefficiency&, irowEffective&
  Dim sh1, sh2 As Worksheet
  Set sh1 = Sheets("sheet1")
  Set sh2 = Sheets("sheet2")
  irowInefficiency = 3 ' where that header is
  irowEffective = 6 ' where that header is
  irowFrom = 5 ' the row to copy
' -- to copy a row in sh1 to INSERT into sh2:
  sh2.Rows(irowInefficiency + 1).Insert ' a blank row
  sh1.Rows(irowFrom).Copy sh2.Rows(irowInefficiency + 1) ' then copy
' -- you have to increment all header rows after this one
  irowEffective = irowEffective + 1 ' because it increases
End Sub
```