# vba copy red rows to new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I'm using two codes in my audit books to create a summary worksheet for corrections. I'm having problems with my second code, one that is intended to find any row with red text and copy it to the new worksheet. I believe it might do what I intend, but it locks my computer up. Any and all suggestions would be helpful.

```
Sub correction()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, j As Long
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ERC DATABASE CORRECTION")
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    For j = 3 To 8000
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim row As Range
        Dim cell As Range
        Set rng = Range("H3:BF9000")
        For Each row In rng.Rows
            For Each cell In row.Cells
                For i = 1 To Len(cell.Value)
                    If cell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Color = vbRed _
                                        And cell.Value <> "" Then
                        lastRow = lastRow + 1
                        ws1.Rows(j).EntireRow.Copy ws2.Range("A" & lastRow)
                    End If
                Next i
            Next cell
        Next row
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA, Copying Colored Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50192444/excel-vba-copying-colored-rows)

Comment: Wow that's got some work to do! Looping through every character of every cell in a range of 458,847 cells

Comment: Depending on whether the  cells are colored by Conditional Formatting you may need to handle it differently but there are several examples on this site and others.  Also it's not a good idea to `Dim` variables within a loop, and I'd recommend adding `Option Explicit` to the top of [every] module [always] to help identify undeclared variables. (like yours). The first step you should take is to **step through the code** line by line to determine exactly what's going on. Tips on that and more in Chip Pearson's [**Debugging VBA**](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx).

Comment: It looks like you're copying the whole row for every character that's red. Put in an Exit For or two.

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor Good point - except it's also every cell in each row, so wouldn't that be "every character in 8997*8997*16384 = 1,326,219,411,456 cells"?  Pfft, a quadrillion loops shouldn't that *that* long, right?  :)~

Comment: @ashleedawg Oh yeah, I didn't pick up on that outer 'J' for loop, looks to be surplus to requirements :) ... @XojieRyden I would also probably use that lastrow variable to reduce the scope of the for loop by assigning the range based on it: `Set rng = Range("H3:BF" & lastrow)` right now it will get to the already copied cells and duplicate them again if `lastrow` is below 9000

Comment: On the other hand, @ashleedawg, there's nothing at all wrong with declaring variables within a loop, VBA doesn't care so long as the variable is declared before it's used. It will _not_ be redeclared/cleared/reinitialized/etc within the loop, it's simply easier to know how it's declared when it's done so closer to its usage. +1 for everything else.

Comment: I'll get to work on redesigning it. Sorry I didn't realize half of my issues.